# How to check JSON string for list using Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm reading strings from a file that are in JSON format, all of which could be slightly different. Specifically the following examples:

No List Example

```
[{"pricing-model":{"qualifier":{"and":{"all":{"equals":{"constant":...
```

List Example

```
{"pricing-model":{"qualifier":{"or":{"and":[{"all":{"equals":{"constant":...
```

If the string contains a list, I need to process it differently than if does not have a list.

Example Code

```
with open('my.jason') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in data:
        item = [item]
        # Get dictionary items
        item.get('pricing-model',{}).get('qualifier',{}).get('and',{}).get('all',{})\
                                    .get('equals',{}).get('constant',{})

        # Get list items
        item.get('pricing-model',{}).get('qualifier',{}).get('and',[])
```

But how do I validate if the sting contains a list so I can run the correct .get?

Answer (score 1):

```
if isinstance(item['pricing-model']['qualifier']['and'], list):
    # Get list items
    item.get('pricing-model',{}).get('qualifier',{}).get('and',[])
else:
    item.get('pricing-model',{}).get('qualifier',{}).get('and',{}).get('all',{})\
                                    .get('equals',{}).get('constant',{})
```